# Styling the default map at construction time?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm just starting to learn the v3 API and am trying to understand how to style the default map at construction. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html#styling_the_default_map) is somewhat vague (or I'm too much of a noob to understand it) and I can't seem to find any example code on how to add map styles to the MapOptions object.

Could someone show how to add styles directly in mapOptions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `styles` property of the `MapOptions` object?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
    {center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
     styles: [{featureType:"administrative", elementType:"all", stylers:[{hue:"#dae6c3"},{saturation:22},{lightness:-5}]}]
    });
```

Documentation is at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html.

(Edited to fix small syntax error)

Comment: I have though I just didn't know how the syntax and couldn't find any example code. Now I do. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, it would be appreciated if you could select the check mark next to this answer.  Thanks!